# How to detect collision between a graphic and a Sprite in phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In my game I want to implement a range sort of feature that would restrict players area. I tried to draw a graphic circle and assign it physics properties. Then I setup collision detection between sprite and graphic. The code shows no errors but the collision is not detected.
I followed the following tutorial.

[Graphic and Sprite](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/40117-how-to-collide-a-sprite-with-a-graphic/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'phaser-example',
    loader: {
      baseURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/samme/phaser-examples-assets@v2.0.0/assets/',
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    },
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
      default: 'arcade'
  },
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create,
    update:update
  }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
var player;

function preload()
{
  this.load.image('dude', 'sprites/phaser-dude.png')
}

function create ()
{
  player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 100, 'dude');
  player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
  
  var graphics = this.add.graphics({ fillStyle: { color: 0xff0000 } });
  var circle = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(50, 50, 25);
  graphics.fillCircleShape(circle);
  this.physics.add.existing(graphics);
  
  cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
  
  this.physics.add.collider(player, graphics);

}

function update()
{
  if (cursors.left.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityX(-160);
  }
  else if (cursors.right.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityX(160);
  }
  else if (cursors.down.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityY(160);

  } 
  else if (cursors.up.isDown)
  {
      player.setVelocityY(-160);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.17.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```